# "Mariscal de campo" for "quarterback"

Tags: traducción, historia, deportes

The American football position of *quarterback* is sometimes translated to Spanish as *mariscal de campo* (literally [field marshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_marshal)) It does not seem like this is the *official* translation since RAE limits [mariscal de campo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?IDLEMA=76637&NEDIC=Si) to its military meaning.

While the name certainly fits the role, where and when did this translation originate? What individual or organization came up with this translation?

Answer (score 1):

Searching in Google Books, shows that translation being already used back in 1969.

This is a newspaper/magazine called [Hispano americano](http://books.google.es/books?num=11&hl=es&id=4pUYAQAAIAAJ) from 1969. Search for ["dos de ellas"](http://books.google.es/books?num=11&hl=es&id=4pUYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dos%20de%20ellas%22#search_anchor) and ["mariscal de campo"](http://books.google.es/books?num=11&hl=es&id=4pUYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22mariscal%20de%20campo%22#search_anchor). Take a look on the snippets of page 59, left column. It is definitely related to sports, possibly to American football.

I know it is not a complete answer, but could be an starting point to more skilled researchers :)

Comment: This is an interesting find since it applies to baseball: based on page 59, it seems like the _mariscal de campo_ is one of the managers from the Mexican league. The next paragraph mentions the [Diablos Rojos de México](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablos_Rojos_del_M%C3%A9xico) and  [Aguila de Veracruz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rojos_del_%C3%81guila_de_Veracruz) teams.

Comment: The dates may be inaccurate for this magazine in Google Books. I found an issue of [Hispano Americano](http://books.google.es/books?id=gK1MAAAAYAAJ&q=%22mejor+mariscal+de+campo%22&dq=%22mejor+mariscal+de+campo%22&hl=es&sa=X&ei=3kVET52AIs2PsAKH4c3CDw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA) from 1944 that mentions [Joe Montana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Montana).